# Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: serialization, utf-8, magento2

Getting "Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" error on admin panel while logged-in. We have upgraded the magento version from 2.0 to 2.3.2

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
#1 Magento\Framework\Translate->_saveCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php:224]

## 2 Magento\Framework\Translate->loadData() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php:245]